# Angular unit test for imported local JSON file

Tags: json, angular, unit-testing

I am trying to make a unit test for local JSON file.

Below is the component file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import user from '../../../models/user.json';
import group from '../../../models/user/group.json';

@Component({
  selector: 'users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.scss'],
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
  data;
  subGroups = [];
  constructor() {this.data = user, this.subGroups[group.label] = group ; }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

This is the spec file:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { UsersComponent } from './users.component';
import { ModelComponent } from '../model/model.component';

fdescribe('UsersComponent', () => {
  let component: UsersComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<UsersComponent>;
  const user: any = require('../../../mocks/model.json');
  const group: any = require('../../../mocks/subModel.json');

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [UsersComponent],
      imports: [],
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UsersComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.data = user;
    component.subGroups[group.label] = group;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('value of data should equal value of imported JSON primary model', () => {
    expect(component.data.label).toBe('Model');
  });

  it('should assign subModel value to SubGroupsArray', () => {
    expect(component.subGroups['SubModel']['label']).toBe('SubModel');
  });
});
```

This is the JSON files:

model.json:

```
{
    "label": "Model",
    "name" : "user",
}
```

subModel.json:

```
{
    "label": "SubModel",
    "name": "group",
}
```

The issue is that the unit test sometimes fails, and sometimes not (without any further changes to the spec file, especially when I run this unit tests with other components as well).

Below is the error:

TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

Appreciate your support.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who came across this question, I realized that I don't have to redo the logic done in the constructor, as a matter of fact, all logic of constructor is done with the testBest, even the real JSON files are being imported, and I don't have to even import the mock JSON file. Which brought me to question, whether it is really necessary to test constructors of Angular components.

Anyways, the issue which I was facing was not related to JSON after all. The issue was that I was testing for two components, which share the same template selector, so when the template was rendered twice, the integration tests were failing.

All I have to do is to remove (fixture.detectChanges()) which were not needed in my case.

Thanks,

Comment: I don't get it. I have the same question. Could you please speak more specific?